# Stop caching files with Java

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to avoid caching my custom js file because I change them often and the client caches old js files.

So I'm trying a solution (http://www.baeldung.com/cachable-static-assets-with-spring-mvc) but it's not working. It simply doesn't change the name of the js file like it's supposed to do.

I'm using Spring MVC 5

#### WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler()
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="../resources/js/pageJS/login.js" />"></script>
```

#### web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>resourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any idea what's doing on?

`../resources/js/pageJS/login.js` **keeps the same name**

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you have need to use

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/js/")
```

instead of

```
registry.addResourceHandler()
```

depending on the location of the login.js file

Also, change 1 second to say, 30 seconds, to give some breathing space to Spring :)

Comment: I also tried `registry.addResourceHandler("../webapp/resources/**").setCachePeriod(0);` but it still caches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller class's request mapping method:-

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView preventCache(HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setHeader("Expires", "Tue, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:01 GMT");
    response.setHeader("Last-Modified", new Date().toString());
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    return new ModelAndView("viewName");
}
```

Comment: I have like 50 of ModelAndView controller. surely there's a better way

Comment: have a filter for them or something. otherwise also you may have some number of views also :-)

Comment: can you be more especific? I'm new with this

Comment: have a common method in a parent class or something and inherit that class with this method? and adding in all methods?

Comment: at least give it a try first and then improvisation could be done :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header**

tag: server

There are two aspects to this rule:

- For static components: implement "Never expire" policy by setting far
  future Expires header
- For dynamic components: use an appropriate    Cache-Control header to
  help the browser with conditional requests

Web page designs are getting richer and richer, which means more scripts, stylesheets, images, and Flash in the page. A first-time visitor to your page may have to make several HTTP requests, but by using the Expires header you make those components cacheable. This avoids unnecessary HTTP requests on subsequent page views. Expires headers are most often used with images, but they should be used on all components including scripts, stylesheets, and Flash components.

Browsers (and proxies) use a cache to reduce the number and size of HTTP requests, making web pages load faster. A web server uses the Expires header in the HTTP response to tell the client how long a component can be cached. This is a far future Expires header, telling the browser that this response won't be stale until April 15, 2010.

```
  Expires: Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT
```

If your server is Apache, use the ExpiresDefault directive to set an expiration date relative to the current date. This example of the ExpiresDefault directive sets the Expires date 10 years out from the time of the request.

```
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
```

Keep in mind, if you use a far future Expires header you have to change the component's filename whenever the component changes. At Yahoo! we often make this step part of the build process: a version number is embedded in the component's filename, for example, yahoo_2.0.6.js.

Using a far future Expires header affects page views only after a user has already visited your site. It has no effect on the number of HTTP requests when a user visits your site for the first time and the browser's cache is empty. Therefore the impact of this performance improvement depends on how often users hit your pages with a primed cache. (A "primed cache" already contains all of the components in the page.) We measured this at Yahoo! and found the number of page views with a primed cache is 75-85%. By using a far future Expires header, you increase the number of components that are cached by the browser and re-used on subsequent page views without sending a single byte over the user's Internet connection.

**Leverage Browser Caching**

This rule triggers when PageSpeed Insights detects that the response from your server does not include caching headers or if the resources are specified to be cached for only a short time.

Overview

Fetching resources over the network is both slow and expensive: the download may require multiple roundtrips between the client and server, which delays processing and may block rendering of page content, and also incurs data costs for the visitor. All server responses should specify a caching policy to help the client determine if and when it can reuse a previously fetched response.

Recommendations

Each resource should specify an explicit caching policy that answers the following questions: whether the resource can be cached and by whom, for how long, and if applicable, how it can be efficiently revalidated when the caching policy expires. When the server returns a response it must provide the Cache-Control and ETag headers:

- Cache-Control defines how, and for how long the individual response
  can be cached by the browser and other intermediate caches. To learn
  more, see caching with Cache-Control.
- ETag provides a revalidation token that is automatically sent by the
  browser to check if the resource has changed since the last time it
  was requested. To learn more, see validating cached responses with
  ETags.

To determine the optimal caching policy for your site, please use the following guides:

- Defining optimal Cache-Control policy
- Invalidating and updating cached responses
- Caching checklist

We recommend a minimum cache time of one week and preferably up to one year for static assets, or assets that change infrequently. If you need precise control over when resources are invalidated we recommend using a URL fingerprinting or versioning technique - see invalidating and updating cached responses link above.